# No transform from [base_link] to [/map]

Tags: ros, urdf, urdf-tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I started to create my URDF robot model, using [ros tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch) as reference.
But when I try to visualize the model using rviz, an error happens:

.Global Options

.Global Status: warning

- Fixed frame: No tf data. Actual error: Fixed Frame [/map] does not exist

1. Grid (Grid)
2. Robot Model (Robot Model):

- Status: Error
- base_link: No transform from [base_link] to [/map]

What am I missing here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10762/no-transform-from-%5Bbase_link%5D-to-%5B/map%5D/) by [Vinipsmaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/912/vinipsmaker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2011-07-28

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I may not be considering this correctly, but it may be as simple as changing your "`fixed frame`" under "`.Global Options`" to <strike>"`/`", "`/world`", or some fixed frame that you do have a transform for.</strike> "`/base_link`"

---

Originally posted by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 13

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-07-28**:
According to the error message, I guess the fixed frame should be /base_link.

**Comment by [Clancy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20877/clancy/) on 2015-04-02**:
Nice. Thank you.

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2017-06-03**:
How do you change this? It appears to be a readonly field in RViz.

**Comment by [roark](https://answers.ros.org/users/30705/roark/) on 2017-06-11**:
thanks! It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rviz fixed frame is the frame that will act as the origin of coordinates on rviz. You can use whichever frame you want, as long as transforms exist between this frame and the rest of the frames published (e.g. robot frames: base_link, laser, etc.).

You've set the rviz fixed frame to /map, which is the frame that's usually used for navigation, but no node is publishing the transform between the map frame and the base_link frame on your robot. You should publish this transform if you really need to set /map as the fixed frame, or either change the fixed frame to some of the frames defined on your robot. This last option is the quickest if you only need to visualize the robot model.

---

Originally posted by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) with karma: 1071 on 2011-07-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-07-02**:
That's true. But what if you want all in the /map frame?
I have /map->/odom->base_footprint->base_link->wheel and the individual transforms between parent and child are all defined. But it still gives the above error for /map to /base_link? Does tf not compute the total tf from individual tfs?

**Comment by [mgrallos](https://answers.ros.org/users/91433/mgrallos/) on 2022-04-19**:
Hello how do I exactly do that?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On the left-hand side of RViz will be your "Displays" tab. Under there, drop down "Global Options" (with the gear icon). Double click the area next to the right of "Fixed Frame", and a dropdown will appear with different frames. Select "base" and you should be good!

---

Originally posted by [SantiagoD](https://answers.ros.org/users/114513/santiagod/) with karma: 11 on 2022-08-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1